# how can i add rollup functionality in sugarcrm(ce)

Tags: sugarcrm

Can any one tell how to add roll up functionality in sugarCRM(Ce).

Our requirement is to "sum of project amounts to roll up to opportunity amount field in sugar crm"

Comment: Your question is too broad and I flagged it. Question should be specific and clear to answer.

Comment: I want get sum of amount of all products in an opportunity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it by writing `after_save logic hook` as described below:

I have achived similar functionality where `sum of pending amount of each cases will be store in accounts module`.

```
$customer_id = $_REQUEST['mc_companyusers_cases_1mc_companyusers_ida'];

if($customer_id){

    $rs = $bean->db->query("SELECT cc.pending_payment_c FROM mc_companyusers_cases_1_c m inner join  cases c on  m.`mc_companyusers_cases_1cases_idb` = c.`id` inner join cases_cstm cc on cc.`id_c` = c.`id` where m.`mc_companyusers_cases_1mc_companyusers_ida` = '".$customer_id."'");
    $total_pending_amount = 0;
    while($row = $bean->db->fetchByAssoc($rs)){
        $total_pending_amount += $row['pending_payment_c'];
    }

    $bean->db->query("Update mc_companyusers_cstm set total_pending_payment_c='".$total_pending_amount."' where id_c='".$customer_id."'");

}
```

So you can map project module with cases and opportunity module with account in above query.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a field with a function that dynamically calculates the sum. 
Or use a logic hook that adds to a real db field whenever a submodule item gets added.